# UWP Shared File Storage

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

In a UWP app, is there a place that I can store files that multiple apps from the same dev can access? Preferably a folder that can roam between computers.

In my case, I want two apps to share an SQLite database. One app edits the database and the other reads from it. I want a place that both apps can interact with the database file without having to manually copy the database from one app package folder to the other. I also was trying to figure out a way for this feature to work with the windows 10 "roaming files" so I can use the same updated database between phone and pc seamlessly.

Comment: You can use the [publisher cache folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx) to share files between apps from the same publisher. Note, however, that the publisher cache folder does not roam.

Answer (score 1):

You have the ability to access other app's data using `AppService`.

> Data sharing between apps
>
> In other scenarios, apps may need to share data without sending the
>   user into another app. For example, the sales app can display sales by
>   region or store, and when that data is categorized by product, you
>   might want to show how many products are available in a store or
>   region. Although the inventory app would be the best source for that
>   data, launching the inventory app in this case would disrupt the user
>   experience. That’s the exact scenario app services are designed to
>   handle.

You can read more about it here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/

For the roaming part, the app served data can store data in Roaming folder or using cloud.